# What is a UIScrollView's "content view"?

Tags: ios, properties, uiscrollview, uitableview

I'm trying to understand UIScrollView's `contentInset` and `contentOffset` properties. [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) frequently refer to the "content view" when talking about properties of UIScrollView.

Say I have a UITableViewController subclass which a few basic cells in a grouped style. **What would be the "content view" in this case?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `UIScrollView` allows you to scroll content that is stored in a number of other views (which would normally be subviews of the `UIScrollView`).

The "Content View" is used to refer to the whole of that content, so for example the ContentSize property of the scrollview is the total size of all of the content across which it can scroll. This could be one large view or a range of subviews if you were using the paging property of a `UIScrollView`.

Hth.

Comment: and a UITableView is put *inside* a UIScrollView (and becomes the scroll view's content -- the thing that's being displayed).